# Tool for translating PDAs to CFGs

Tags: automata-theory, fl.formal-languages, grammars, software

We know that all push down automata are representable using context-free grammars. Furthermore, there is an algorithm to construct a CFG from any PDA (e.g. Sipser's proof in intro to theory of computation).

Are there any tools which do this translation? I.e. I can put in a set of transition functions and it will return an equivalent CFG.

Comment: funny. normally one wants the other way around :)

Comment: mmm. I would attribute that proof to Chomsky, Evey and Schützenberger.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jflap is pretty nice and can do this. See here: http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/jflap/.

Comment: Does is implement the usual construction that is used for proving equivalence of PDA and CFG (we called it "triple construction") or does it do something else?

Comment: @Raphael, apparently it does: http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/jflap/tutorial/pda/cfg/index.html